# VS Code Tuning: Merging Explorer, Search and Source Control in the Panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now in VS Code there are a lot of tuning possibilities.

Right now I have this Side Bar and the Panel on the left side, and when I want to see the explorer I click on it and if I want to see the SourceControll I must click again to see the Source Control.

Is it posible to make those 3 Elements share the Panel? or at least two of them?

Comment: Drag the Source Control icon into the Side Bar when the Explorer files are shown.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks! I've been looking for this since that update.  It's been driving me bananas.